# How to automatically mute/unmute html video on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, iframe

I'm editing a website for a client, and he never mentioned that there will be some javascript edits included, but here we are. Since I'm not familiar with js at all, I could really really use your help.
So, the thing is, there is a video (so called playable ad for mobile) in the header. When you click on it, you get to play some game with the sound ON. What my client wants is when you scroll down and the video is not visible anymore to MUTE the sound, and UNMUTE it when you scroll up.
I haven't built this website, I'm just editing it.

I've spent days on this, reading different posts and solutions here and on Google, but whatever I tried didn't work. Since I'm not familiar with Javascript, I suppose that I'm doing something wrong. I suppose that I can't just copy someone else's code and expect it to work, but I probably have to change variable name or something else. But I don't know how to change it and make it work.

```
<a class="img" href="">
<iframe src="https://appsposure.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/bask.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>  
<img class="phone-img lazyloaded" src="https://appsposure.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/phone-2.png" alt="" data-lazy-src="https://appsposure.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/phone-2.png" data-was-processed="true"><noscript><img class="phone-img" src="https://appsposure.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/phone-2.png" alt=""></noscript>                                
</a>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408138/how-to-mute-a-html5-video-on-scrollposition) is the solution that I've tried multiple times, but it doesn't work since I probably don't know how to adjust it for my website.

Also, [here](https://appsposure.com/playable-ads/) is the link to the website I'm working on (I'm talking about the video in the header, the one with basketball player on it).

If there is anyone willing to help me, I would really appreciate it, since I'm struggling for days, and I'm just too stupid for this.

Comment: do you have a separate scripts file or embedded scripts in the html?

Answer (score 2):

added basketball-player id on the iframe

```html
<a class="img">
<iframe id='basketball-player' src="https://appsposure.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/bask.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>  
<img class="phone-img lazyloaded" src="https://appsposure.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/phone-2.png" alt="" data-lazy-src="https://appsposure.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/phone-2.png" data-was-processed="true"><noscript><img class="phone-img" src="https://appsposure.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/phone-2.png" alt=""></noscript>                                
</a>
```

using embedded scripts in html.

```js
<script>
window.addEventListener("scroll", muteOnScroll);

// function for the eventlistener
function muteOnScroll() {
    // if the iframe is out of view
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 610) {
        // targeting the iframe with the id of basketball-player to turn off sound
        document.getElementById("basketball-player").volume = 0.0;
    // else the iframe must be in the view so the sound should be on
    } else {
        document.getElementById("basketball-player").volume = 1.0;
    }
}
</script>
```

used 610 because that it was I found the top to be when I scrolled the iframe out of view.

EDIT

used part of what you provided and some of this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/mute)

```js
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900){ 
        iframe.mute();
    } else { 
        iframe.unmute(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work. I've added the id to the iframe, but nothing happened.
I failed to mention that the website is built in WordPress using Oxygen Builder. There are separate fields for PHP&HTML, CSS and JAVASCRIPT. I've added your code to the JAVASCRIPT field where also are other scripts and Jquery

Comment: Originally this video was paused on scroll but my client wanted to remove that and only to mute it. Here is the code that has been used originally, maybe it can help you:
`jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 900){
  var closeGame = jQuery('header iframe');
       closeGame.detach(); 
  jQuery('.close-game').css('display', 'none');
}
else{
  closeGame.appendTo('header .col-md-7 .img');  
}
});`

Comment: sorry to bother you, but do you have any more thoughts on this?

Comment: check edit @mockingjay_89 let me know. I'll try to help

Comment: For some reason it's not working :(
You can check too, maybe it's because of my server's cache, I don't know.
Man, this mute function will kill me for sure. 
I don't know, maybe something else blocks this code from working, is that possible?

Comment: Can you sent me an email to jelenabrocilovic@yahoo.com

Answer (score -1):

You can check if an element is visible with this function

```
function checkVisible(elm) {
  var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
  var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
  return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
}
```

from the question [Check if element is visible on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353934/check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen).

Then you attach a function to the `onscroll` event handler of the window with

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  // CODE
};
```

You can handle the video being scrolled with some code like this:

```
video.muted = !checkVisible(video);
```

with `video` being the video's element.

This snippet shows this in action:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var videoPreviouslyVisible = false;

window.onscroll = function() {
  wrapper.style.backgroundColor = checkVisible(video) ? '#4f4' : '#f44';
  video.muted = !checkVisible(video);
};

function checkVisible(elm) {
  var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
  var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
  return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 400%;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f44;
}

#video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 33%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="video"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I've looked into this further and it seems like you're trying to mute an ***IFrame*** instead of a ***video***.
This is ***not*** ***possible*** as it is a seperate html website embedded into yours.
You may be able to access the embedded JavaScript code though it would most probably require the assistance of the original developer of this browser game.

My answer still applies to any user looking to mute any DOM element with the `muted` property upon disappearing from view.

I would advise you to contact the original developer and ask him to implement a convenient way to mute the JavaScript game engine the "playable ad" is implemented in.